# How to submit data from Ext.FormPanel with tabs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

There are several tabs on a FormPanel:

[image]

Code:

```
var podform = new Ext.FormPanel({
 labelAlign: 'left',
 id: 'tab_6',
 frame:true,
 title: 'Договоры подряда',
 bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
 width: 600,
 listeners: {
'activate' :  function(podform,records,options) {
       console.log("store:"+store_form);
    this.loaded = true;
    var record = store_form.getAt(0);
    podform.getForm().loadRecord(record);
}
 },
 reader : new Ext.data.XmlReader({
record : 'zem',
//      success: '@success'
}, [
  ]),
 items: []
});
```

podform.add(tabs_pod);

Now i try submit data to server:

```
    podform.addButton({
    text: 'Submit',
    //disabled:true,
    handler: function(){
        podform.getForm().submit({
            url:url_servlet+'submit.jsp',
            waitMsg:'Saving Data...',
            success: function(form, action) {
                Ext.Msg.show({
                 title:'Success'
                ,msg:'Form submitted successfully'
                ,modal:true
                    ,icon:Ext.Msg.INFO
                ,buttons:Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But firebug says that i subbmit data only with panels that I have seen. Its means if i not click on second tab i cant get data from it.
Its possible to fix it?

**UPDATE**

When i use `deferredRender:false,` first tab shows normal but another tabs looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you are seeing is that the tab panel is not rendering the fields in inactive tabs dues to lazy rendering - a performance enhancing technique. You can try to explicitly force rendering of those sub panels with `deferredRender:false`

see full doc here

ExtJS 3.4 -> http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.TabPanel-cfg-deferredRender

ExtJS 4.1 -> http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-deferredRender

Comment: I added the reference to the 3.4 API, cause the OP seems not to use ExtJS 4. Even if the result is totally the same

Comment: I have a problem with `deferredRender`. Look at UPDATE please.

Comment: hmm is it the height issue? or field render timing issue? If you inspect your tab with Illuminations it will show you whether any chldren have been added to the panel. It will also show you where they are (even if not visible on the screen).

Comment: I Haven't Mentioned it? Illuminations for Developers - a Firebug plugin for Firefox. http://www.illuminations-for-developers.com/ - get free eval version - but it's worth every penny in my opinion. I use it daily.

Comment: But what i can see in Illumitation? I see that all tabs was rendered. Maybe i miss some Config options in tabpanel?